# KQL query - Relatively select data for today in where clause

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-monitor

I need a way to select dataset "since midnight" in Azure Monitor - e.g relative to current day.

Using ago(1d) is obviously not doing the trick :)

```
StorageBlobLogs
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) and StatusText contains "success"
```

Cheers

Comment: For better query performance, you should consider replacing `contains` with `has`, which is much more performant (just note a semantic difference between the two: `contains` looks for any substring, while `has` looks for full words).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using `startofday()`.

For example: `... | where TimeGenerated > startofday(now())`